# Android Room database query does not return id column

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, fts4

The problem is that the query returns all columns except  'id'

I use fts4 and in docs it says:

> FTS-enabled tables always use a primary key of type INTEGER and with
>   the column name "rowid". If your FTS-table-backed entity defines a
>   primary key, it must use that type and column name.

here is my entity class:

```
@Fts4
@Entity(tableName = "projects")
public class Project {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "rowid")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "start_date")
    private String startDate;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "end_date")
    private String endDate;
    private String description;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "icon_path")
    private String iconPath;
    private long budget;


public Project(String name, String startDate, String endDate, String description, String iconPath, long budget) {
    this.name = name;
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
    this.description = description;
    this.iconPath = iconPath;
    this.budget = budget;
}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public String getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}

public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getIconPath() {
    return iconPath;
}

public void setIconPath(String iconPath) {
    this.iconPath = iconPath;
}

public long getBudget() {
    return budget;
}

public void setBudget(long budget) {
    this.budget = budget;
}
```

and here is my simple query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM projects")
public LiveData<List<Project>> getAllProjectsI);
```

I got a warning :

> app.aarsham.projeno.data.Model.Project has some fields [rowid] which
>   are not returned by the query. If they are not supposed to be read
>   from the result, you can mark them with @Ignore annotation. You can
>   suppress this warning by annotating the method with
>   @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH). Columns returned by
>   the query: name, start_date, end_date, description, icon_path, budget.
>   Fields in app.aarsham.projeno.data.Model.Project: rowid, name,
>   start_date, end_date, description, icon_path, budget.

and an error:

> The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [id] in
>   app.aarsham.projeno.data.Model.Project even though they are annotated
>   as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query:
>   [name,start_date,end_date,description,icon_path,budget]

can anyone help about this?

Comment: remove from @Fts4 Project class

Comment: I had the same issue and removing `rowid` column from the entity resolved the error.  I hope it would be of your help.

Comment: I wonder what to do when you actually use the FTS? Because I'm getting same warning...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When using FTS, you have to explicitly include the row "`rowid`" in your query even if you are using `select *` to select all rows.

Basically, the query should be like `` @Query("SELECT *, `rowid ` FROM projects") ``

Comment: I would have never thought of this solution...thanks!